# How to use 2 table Model in Controller Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

Mysql I have user and group tables

User table

`id`, `username`, `email`, `fullname`, `password`, `avatar`, `sign`, `created`, `created_by`, `modified`, `modified_by`, `register_time`, `register_ip`, `active_code`, `active_time`, `status`, `ordering`, `group_id`

Group Table

`id`, `name`, `status`, `ordering`, `created`, `created_by`, `modified`, `modified_by`

GroupsTable.php

```
public function itemInSelectBox($arrParam = null, $options = null)
{
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $sql = new Sql($adapter);
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('group');
    $select->columns(['id', 'name']);
    $selectString = $sql->buildSqlString($select);
    $items = $adapter->query($selectString, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    $result = [];
    if (!empty($items)) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $result[$item->id] = $item->name;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I have already got the user list in indexAction in UserController, but now I want to get the list group name and group id in the `Group` table to put in the selectbox in view. How to UserController use itemInSelectBox()

Comment: What have you done and tried? Any errors, if so, which and how did you try to solve them? Please update the question following guidelines set out in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just call that model in UserController